# Get all keys without translations

Tags: php, laravel, database, eloquent, laravel-8

I have this entity :

```
class Keyword extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = "keywords";

    protected $fillable = [
        'key',
        'description',
        'project_page_id'
    ];

    public function keywordsTranslated()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(KeywordTranslated::class);
    }

    public function projectPage()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(ProjectPage::class)->withDefault();
    }
  }
```

And this one :

```
class KeywordTranslated extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = "keywords_translated";

    protected $fillable = [
        'translation',
        'language_id',
        'keyword_id'
    ];

    public function keyword()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Keyword::class)->withDefault();
    }

    public function language()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Language::class)->withDefault();
    }
}
```

And I want to get all `keywords` that don't have a `keywordTranslated` for a specific `language`.

I tried like this :

```
public function searchTranslatedKeys(
    int $projectPageId,
    int $curentPage,
    int $languageId,
    string $search = null
) {
    $query = $this->model->newQuery();
    $query->where('project_page_id', $projectPageId);
    if ($search) {
        $query->where('key', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%");
    }
    $query->doesntHave('keywordsTranslated');
    $query->orderBy('id', 'DESC');

    if ($search) {
        return $query->get();
    }

    return $query->get()->forPage($curentPage, 20);
}
```

But in this case my return is empty.

For example, in keywords I have :

```
id          key                description
1           addItem            description for this item
2           deleteItem         description for this item 
3           editItem           description for this item
```

In kewordTranslated :

```
translation             keyword_id                     language_id
Add item                1                               1
Add item new            1                               2
Delete item             2                               1
```

I want to get all keys without language `2`, for previous example I should received 2 keys with id = 2 & 3, because these keys don't have a `kewordTranslated` for this language. If language id will be 1 I should get only keyword with id = 3, because this keyword didn't have a `kewordTranslated` for this language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [whereDoesntHave](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence)

it limit your results based on the absence of a relationship:

instead of:

```
 $query->doesntHave('keywordsTranslated');
```

you can use:

```
 $query->whereDoesntHave('keywordsTranslated',function ($query) use ($languageId) {
            $query->where('language_id','=',$languageId);
        });
```

Comment: thank you, is working